# Service Now REST API script for listening from DevOps web hooks

Tags: azure-devops, webhooks, servicenow

I am wondering how connect between DevOps Boards Incidents and Tasks (web hooks used) to ServiceNow. The requirement is Service Now will need to listen every time there is an update to Azure DevOps boards incidents or Tasks.

I have created a Scripted REST API at Service Now with the following Example script:

```
`(function process(/*RESTAPIRequest*/ request, /*RESTAPIResponse*/ response) {
    var body = request.body.data;
    var eventType = request.headers['auth_token'];  
    var workItem = body.resource;
    var title = workItem.fields['System.Title'];
    var description = workItem.fields['System.Description'];
    var state = workItem.fields['System.State'];
    var priority = workItem.fields['System.priority'];
    
    if(eventType == 'workitem.created') {
        title = workItem.fields['System.Title'];
        description = workItem.fields['System.Description'];
        state = workItem.fields['System.State'];
    } else if(eventType == 'workitem.updated') {
        title = workItem.fields['System.Title'];
        description = workItem.fields['System.Description'];
        state = workItem.fields['System.State'];        
    }
    response.setStatus(200);
})(request, response);`
```

Now, Just wondering how to invoke this API end point when there is an update.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/service-hooks/overview?view=azure-devops

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66701660/109941

Answer (score 1):

If you are on the Scripted REST Resource form in ServiceNow, then you should see a "Explore REST API" link at the bottom of the page. If you click that link it will take you page that you can use to test your API. Right below the "Send" button there should be links to generate code samples to call your API. [image: Code Samples]